# How to show a progress dialog at loading audio on MediaPlayer obj

Tags: android, media-player, progressdialog

I want to load an audio file from internet on MediaPlayer object.

it's my code:

```
try {
    mp.setDataSource(AUDIO URL);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
}
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
catch (IllegalStateException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

but problem is that it's take a lot of time loading audio.

Help me to show a spinning progress dialog before loading audio to after that.

If question is incomplete tell me to complete decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite a dublicate, but this question has a progress bar while preparing, it would be "quite" easy to modify to progress dialog or something else:

[Progress Bar while media player is preparing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475115/progress-bar-while-media-player-is-preparing)

Answer (score 3):

you will need to add MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener to MediaPlayer to show progress dialog when it's preparing as :

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, 
                            "Loading Title", "Loading Message");
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
               if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                  progressDialog.dismiss();
               }
                mp.start();
         }
     });
```

Comment: If progress dialog not exist ,what happens?

Comment: @MOHSEN : mean im not getting u ? or u can see [this](http://lab-programming.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-work-around-android-mediaplayer.html) good example

Comment: @MOHSEN : and apart from setOnPreparedListener we have some other Listener to show message when any error occur during playing or preparing in MediaPlayer instance like OnErrorListener and OnCompletionListener

Comment: i say that if progress dialog not exist and **progressDialog.dimiss()** runs what will happen?

Comment: @MOHSEN : i get u plz check my edit answer in that case you will need to check is progressDialog is not null and it's showing using `isShowing()` before calling ` dismiss() `